# Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0 error while parsing data using JSON.parse method

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, parsing

this is the string that is sent from the MVC Controller

```
'[{ "When": "", "Value": "NRMFS0131", "Text": "Achieve Montana" }]'
```

but when I parse this using JSON.parse an exception is thrown saying Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0 error

Please note parsing works completely fine in chrome's console

Comment: The `'` characters are not JSON, you'll need to remove them. Ideally from the response sent from the MVC controller.

Comment: Why send a `string` and parse it instead of just returning json?

Comment: @StephenMuecke well technically, JSON is a string that's parsed. It's just that OP needs to parse this to remove the `'`, then parse it again as JSON :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I meant by using a `JsonResult` (ie `return Json(...);`) from the controller so the `JSON.parse()` is not required

Comment: So show the code from the server end of this transaction. It's highly relevant.

Comment: @mayur How are you returning the JSON from your mvc controller? Are you using Json() which returns JsonResult or are you simply returning string from your controller. Please update the question ASP.NET MVC code as well

Comment: Voted to close due to lack of code to reproduce problem.

Answer (score 1):

After i ran your json in JSONLint/json validator,

This was the issue.

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
'[{ "When": "", "Val
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

The ' is not a valid first character for JSON, it should've been `'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['`

Your issue can be fixed by sending the JSON as it is The ' might be appearing due to you converting to any other type. Hope i helped!

Comment: Well, that identifies the problem. But it's not really an answer unless you can show the OP how to fix it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Added note that he should send the json as json and not as a string. Hope it clarifies his problem.

Comment: Your edit seems confused - JSON *is* a string, by its very definition.

Comment: I can not seem to give further solutions just on my assumption, i also need to know the back end code to provide a good solution, anyways i'll edit the string part.

Answer (score 1):

The `'` characters at the beginning and end are not part of json.

A general tip for such situations - Always validate your json here https://jsonlint.com/. It will give you detailed error messages.

Answer (score 1):

`stringify` your `json` before `parse`.

```js
var str = [{
  "When": "??",
  "Value": "NRMFS0131",
  "Text": "Achieve Montana"
}];
var Result=JSON.stringify(str);
Result=JSON.parse(Result);
console.log(Result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The object is being  constructed and sent from the controller, not constructed in the view

Comment: Hold your json string like above on str in view. .